# Do laptop users experience purple blank screen sometimes after logging in to 18.10?

Tags: laptop, thinkpad

It has happened several times. After entering userid and password, a purple screen with nothing on it shows up. I had to press the power button continuously to force reboot. I am using a Thinkpad X1 Extreme but some other laptops might have the same issue.

Comment: There used to be a very similar problem with 18.04. The problem would occur if you typed the wrong password, and then tried logging in again. In order to not get the purple screen, if you type the wrong password, you must click “Cancel” and then click your user name again. Try this and see if it happens again?

Comment: Thanks. I usually don't type in the password wrong. Could there be other reasons? Currently I am trying to get hybrid gpu working. It "seems" that when I switched the GPU in the BIOS, sometimes this blank purple screen issue appeared.

Comment: The way the question is written, literal answers would be either "yes" or "no", which is not helpful. Now, I would assume you're looking for help, but you haven't actually asked for help, so I'm voting to close this as a bug report. Bug reports should be posted on Launchpad. You can [edit] the question if needed.

Comment: If anyone were to read the questions, they’d see that they’re definitely not exact duplicates.